# I am trying to execute a makefile but I keep getting an error

Tags: c, makefile

I have four different files (main.c selection.c display.c main.h) and i have created a makefile to execute.

error message

```
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -o main main.o display.o selection.o
selection.o: In function `menu':
selection.c:(.text+0xdd): undefined reference to `vendingMachine'
selection.c:(.text+0x118): undefined reference to `loanCalc'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1"
```

this is my main.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "main.h"

int main() {
    char choices[NUM_ITERATIONS];
        double totalAmountSpent = 0.0;

         menu(choices);

        while(userSelect(totalAmountSpent, choices) != 4){
                menu(choices);
        }

    return 0;
}
```

this is my selection.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "main.h"




#define NUM_ITERATIONS 3
int menu(char choices[]){
        int prices[NUM_ITERATIONS][2];   //2d array
        double payments[NUM_ITERATIONS];  // 1d array
        double totalAmountSpent = 0.0;
        int count1 = 0;
        int count2 = 0;


        for (int i=0; i < NUM_ITERATIONS; i++) {
                printf("\nMENU:\n");
                printf("1. Vending machine\n");
                printf("2. Loan\n");
                printf("3. Display\n");
                printf("4. Quit\n");
                int userSelection = userSelect(0, choices);
                choices[i] = userSelection;


                switch (userSelection) {
                        case 1:
                            if (count1 < 3) {
                                choices[i] = 'V';
                                vendingMachine(&totalAmountSpent, prices, choices);
                                count1++;
                        }else{
                                printf("You have reached your limit for this menu option.\n");
                                i--;
                        }
                                break;
                        case 2:
                            if (count2 < 3){
                                choices[i] = 'L';
                                loanCalc(payments);
                                count2++;
                        }else{
                                printf("You have reached your limit for this menu option.\n");
                                i--;
                        }
                                break;

                        case 3:
                                displayData(prices, payments, choices);
                                break;
                        case 4:
                                quit(totalAmountSpent);
                                break;
                        default:
                                printf("Invalid choice. Please try again.\n");
                                i--;
                                  }

                }
                return 0;
}


 int userSelect(double totalAmountSpent, char choices[]) {
        int userSelection;
        printf("Enter your choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &userSelection);
        return userSelection;
        }
```

this is my display.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "main.h"

#define NUM_ITERATIONS 3
void displayData(int prices[][2], double payments[],char choices[]){

        printf("\nChoices made:\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ITERATIONS; i++){
                printf("Iteration %d: %c\n", i +1, choices[i]);
        }

        printf("\nResults:\n");
        for(int i=0; i < NUM_ITERATIONS; i++){
                printf("Iteration %d - Price: %d cents, Loan Payment: $%.21f\n", i+1, prices[i][0], payments[i]);


        }


}

void quit(double totalAmt) {

        printf("Total amount spent on the vending machine: $%.2f\n", totalAmt);
}
```

this is my main.h file:

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H

#define NUM_ITERATIONS 3

int menu(char choices[]);
int userSelect(double totalAmountSpent, char chpices[]);
void vendingMachine(double *totalAmt, int prices[][2], char choices[]);
void loanCalc(double payments[]);
void displayData(int prices[][2], double payments[], char choices[]);
void quit(double totalAmt);

#endif // MAIN_H
```

this is my current makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra

all: main

main: main.o display.o selection.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o main main.o display.o selection.o

main.o: main.c main.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c main.c

display.o: display.c main.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c display.c

selection.o: selection.c main.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c selection.c

clean:
        rm -f main *.o
```

Comment: You're missing the definition of `loanCalc()`. Since it's declared in `main.h`, the definition should be in `main.c`.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this is pretty much that although you _declared_ `vendingMachine` et. al. in your `.h` file, you did _not_ provide a _definition_ in any of your `.c` files

Comment: And since `userSelect()` is defined in `selection.c`, its declaration should be in `selection.h`. Each `.c` file should have its own `.h` file with the declarations of its functions.